# Cannot retrieved form data on uploadify

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I've tried several ways to do this but I simple cannot made it work.

I've a select menu on the form wich is filled by a query from another table, this is for link the categories table with the galery, So I have 2 selects one static and another dinamic.

When I process the upload just the name of the picture are being saved on the database.

Can you guys help me on this matter?

This is the code for JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" langauge="javascript">
                    $( document ).ready( function(){
                            $( '#file_upload' ).uploadify({
                                    'uploader'              : 'uploadfyit1/uploadify.swf',
                                    'script'                : 'uploadfyit1/uploadify.php',
                                    'cancelimg'             : 'uploadfyit1/cancel.png',
                                    'folder'                : 'uploads',
                'debug'                 : false,
                                    'multi'                 : true,
                                    'auto'                  : false,
                'queueSizeLimit': 5, //Para enviar solo un archivo 
    'onQueueFull': function(event, queueSizeLimit) {
        alert("Nao pode mais enviar arquivos! Somente pode enviar" + queueSizeLimit + " por vez.");
        return false;
    },
    'onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
        // you can use here jQuery AJAX method to send info at server-side.
$("#fileUpload").uploadifySettings('scriptData', {'galeria' : $('#galeria').val(), 'regiao' : $('#regiao').val()});
        }
    });   
});
</script>
```

and this for uploadify

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$img        = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$ext        = substr($img, -4);
$img        = md5($img).date("dmYHis").$ext;
$tempFile   = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
$targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $img;

    $galeria = $_REQUEST['galeria'];
    $regiao = $_REQUEST['regiao'];

    $adicionar = mysql_query("INSERT INTO imagens (img_cat_id, img_foto, img_regiao) VALUES('$galeria','$img','$regiao')");

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);
}
```

What happens is both `galeria` and `regiao` are empty.